# Functors and vector of strings

Tags: c++, functor

I'm new to functors theme, so I hope this question will be constructive.

I have array of strings (). I need to calculate the sum of lenghts of these strings with help of functors.

My code:

```
class LengthFinder{
    private:
        size_t sum;
    public:
        LengthFinder():sum(0){}

    void operator()(string elem)
    {
        sum += elem.size();
    }
    operator int()
    {
        return sum;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector< string > array;
    array.push_back("string");
    array.push_back("string1");
    array.push_back("string11");

    string elem;
    int sum = std::for_each(array.begin(), array.end(), LengthFinder(/*??*/));
    return 0;
}
```

What should I pass to LengthFinder(), to get each string and take it size?

Comment: Have you tried to run your code? what do you want to put in LengthFinder?

Comment: You don't have to do anything. Just `LengthFinder()` creates a temporary instance to be used in `for_each`, and `for_each` calls the `operator()` method in that instance.

Comment: However, you might want to change the argument of `operator()` to a constant reference instead, i.e. `void operator()(const std::string& elem)`.

Comment: To @ Joachim Pileborg: Thank you very much! LengthFinder() really works without parameters!)

Comment: Oh by the way, besides the answer from Jerry Coffin, you might also want to read a little about [lambdas in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Lambda_functions_and_expressions), a new feature that makes functors all but obsolete.

Comment: I have gcc vesion 4.4.7 (I have no opportunity to change it now), and lamdas are after 4.5. Thank you for your advice)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `for_each` for this. It *can* be forced to do the job, but it's a fair amount of extra work because it's not really the right tool for the job.

What you want to use is `std::accumulate`, which is built for exactly the sort of thing you're doing.

```
struct length : std::binary_function<size_t, size_t, std::string> {
    size_t operator()(size_t a, std::string const &b) { 
        return a+b.length();
    }
};

// ...
int sum = std::accumulate(array.begin(), array.end(), 0, length());
```

Comment: Thank you! I have corrected my code according to the advice of  @Joachim Pileborg and it is working now. Your advice is exactly what I wanted, so I will use it!

Answer (score 0):

*As stated by the original poster of the question:*

---

SOLUTION:

Nothing should go to the parameters of LengthFinder:

```
 int sum = std::for_each(array.begin(), array.end(), LengthFinder());
```